# Whats an efficent way to put multiple types of users in a db

Tags: mysql, sql, facebook, schema, google-plus

I'm building a website where I will have users logging into the site from multiple sources, including Facebook and Google+ and I want to be able to keep some basic info on each user in my data base, so that I can track the creation of things like comments and posts. How do I efficiently do this in a SQL database. Do I create a new table for each type of user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach is:

- A `USER` table with the common data
- A `FACEBOOK_USER` table (which has it's own PK and a `USER` FK) with the Facebook specific data
- A `GOOGLE_USER` table...

When loading a user, you can join all those tables or you can create a view that contains the join or, if you have many special types, you can load the user and then read the others individually (maybe keep a `IS_x_USER` in the `USER` table to speed this up).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. this makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 4):

You just need two tables, a user table and a usertype table.  The user table would have a column for type that would link to the usertype table and tell you the type.  I would be something basic like this:

```
User (
  Id Int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  UserName VarChar(50) NOT NULL,
  EmailAddress VarChar(100),
  {... More fields generally used by all account types ...}
  UserTypeId Int NOT NULL
)

UserType (
  Id Int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Type VarChar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

If you have information that is specific to each log on type like Google+ or Facebook, you could create a table for each specific log on type.  However, the reality is that you probably will get the same set of basic information fields for all of the different types possible so there is not much to worry about.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. so will the usertype table be like a user ID form the user table, and a type number or something? but will this method allow me to store the actual UserID from facebook or google? because that was the problem i was running into, is if I want to store that id, without the possibility of overlapping the ID's It seemed like I would have to make multiple tables.

Comment: So the User.Id would be unique to each user.  However, two users could have the same UserName but different UserTypeId's.  In this case you would want to use the User.Id column to identify the user in each of your other tables for what user created the information.